# Proof that an property is definable if and only if its axiomatiazable and its complement its axiomatizable

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

For a homework of first-order logic I need to prove that a property, lets call it P, is definable if and only if P is axiomatizable and the complement of P is axiomatizable. 
I have no idea of how to solve this, if you can give me a hint I will appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to people here if you could write what you mean by "property", "definable" and "axiomatizable" (in your class).

Comment: definable is that there exists a set of formulas that describes the property. Moreover the set must contain a finite number of elements.
Aziomatizable is the same thing that definable but the set can contain infinite number of elements.
A property is a subset of all the estructures of a vocabulary L.
In other world, lets struct[L] be all the possibles structures that satisfies L, p is an subset of struct[L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ axiomatize $P$ and its complement, respectively.  Can you think of a sentence $\psi$ such that $T_1 \models \psi$ and $T_2 \models \neg \psi$, provided that $T_1 \cup T_2$ is inconsistent?

Solution:

> By compactness theorem, there exist finitely many $\phi^i_1,\dots,\phi^i_{n_i} \in T_i$ $(i = 1,2)$ such that $\{\phi^i_k : 1 \le k \le n_i, i = 1,2\}$ is inconsistent.  This implies $\models \bigwedge _ {1\le k \le n_1} \phi^1_k \rightarrow \bigvee_ {1 \le k \le n_2} \neg \phi^2_k$.  Let $\psi$ denote the consequent of the conditional.  Then $T_1 \models \psi$ and $T_2 \models \neg \psi$. Let me show $\psi$ defines $P$.  Clearly any structure $\mathfrak M \in P$ satisfies $\psi$, since $\mathfrak M \models T_1$.  Conversely, suppose $\mathfrak M  \models \psi$.  Then $\mathfrak M \not \models \neg \psi$, hence $\mathfrak M \not \models T_2$.  Since $T_2$ axiomatizes the complement of $P$, we have $\mathfrak M \in P$.