# How to prove that if $\mathfrak{K}_2$ is $\Delta$-elementary, then $\mathfrak{K}_1$ is elementary?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I have some problems with this exercise in Chapter VI.3 of Mathematical Logic by Ebbinghaus.

> **3.9 Exercise.** Let $\mathfrak{K}$ and $\mathfrak{K}_1$ be classes of $S$-structures such that $\mathfrak{K}_1 \subseteq \mathfrak{K}$. Let $\mathfrak{K}_2$ be the class of $S$-structures which are in $\mathfrak{K}$ but not in $\mathfrak{K}_1$, that is $\mathfrak{K}_2 = \mathfrak{K} \setminus \mathfrak{K}_1$. Furthermore, let $\mathfrak{K}$ be elementary and $\mathfrak{K}_1$ be $\Delta$-elementary. Show:
>
> (a) $\mathfrak{K}_1$ is elementary $\quad$ iff $\quad$ $\mathfrak{K}_2$ is $\Delta$-elementary $\quad$ iff $\quad$ $\mathfrak{K}_2$ is elementary.

In particular I don't know how to prove the opposite direction of the first line ($\Leftarrow$), that if $\mathfrak{K}_2$ is $\Delta$-elementary, then $\mathfrak{K}_1$ is elementary. I don't know either if the exercise in question is wrong, I've tried to find a counter example, but without success, if anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to mse! I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searcahble) rather than an image (which isn't) so that other users have an easier time finding this. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: Oh, thank you very much @HallaSurvivor ^^

Comment: Actually, maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329502/proof-that-an-property-is-definable-if-and-only-if-its-axiomatiazable-and-its-co) is a better duplicate (it uses compactness, rather than higher powered techniques)

Comment: Thanks @HallaSurvivor I think the one you sent before (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3690279/axiomatizability-of-a-relative-complement) was pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $\mathfrak K_1= \operatorname{Mod}(\Phi_1),$ $\mathfrak K_2= \operatorname{Mod}(\Phi_2),$ and $\mathfrak K = \operatorname{Mod}(\{\varphi\})$. We know $\Phi_1\cup \Phi_2$ is inconsistent, so there is a finite subset $\Phi_2^0\subseteq \Phi_2$ such that $\Phi_1\cup \Phi_2^0$ is inconsistent. Let $$\psi = \left(\bigvee_{\sigma\in \Phi_2^0}\lnot\sigma\right)\land\varphi.$$ Then $\mathfrak K_1= \operatorname{Mod}(\{\psi\}):$

- If $M\models \psi,$ then $M\models \varphi,$ so $M\in \mathfrak K,$
  and $M\models \lnot\sigma$ for some $\sigma\in \Phi_2^0\subseteq
     \Phi_2,$ so $M\notin \mathfrak K_2$ and hence $M\in \mathfrak K_1.$
- If $M\in \mathfrak K_1,$ then $M\in \mathfrak K,$ so $M\models \varphi.$ Also $M\models \Phi_1,$ so $M\not\models \Phi_2^0,$ so there is a $\sigma\in \Phi_2^0$ such that $M\models \lnot \sigma.$ Thus $M\models \psi.$

Comment: If $Inc(\Phi_1\cup\Phi_2)$ so for compactness there is a subset $\Phi_0$ which is inconsistent, how do you know this is of the form $\Phi_1\cup\Phi_2^0$? And if this is true, why does $\bigvee_{\sigma\in\Phi_2^0}\neg\sigma$ guarantee that I will have the class of structures that is complementary to $\mathfrak{K}_2$? As far as I know if $\Phi\subseteq\Psi$, then $Mod(\Psi)=\mathfrak{K}_2\subseteq Mod(\Phi)$, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Compactness says there is a finite subset $\Phi_0\subseteq \Phi_1\cup \Phi_2$ that is inconsistent. Then take $\Phi_2^0 = \Phi_2\cap \Phi_0.$ Then $\Phi_0\subseteq \Phi_1\cup\Phi_2^0,$ so $\Phi_1\cup\Phi_2^0$ is inconsistent. I expanded my answer.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand now, thanks!